# Java F-Bound bound by interface

Tags: java, generics, type-systems, f-bounded-polymorphism

Notation: `Inter` is interface; `Abs[N]` is an abstract class.

The following code works fine in Java without a problem:

```
public class Impl<T extends Abs1<T>> extends Abs2<T> {...}
```

However, if you want to introduce another bound by an interface on `T`, I haven't found any easy way to do it, namely:

```
public class Impl<T extends Inter & Abs1<T>> extends Abs2<T> {...}
```

won't work because `Abs1` as an abstract class cannot be used as a bounding parameter. The simplest, but ugly (is it ugly?) solution I have found is:

```
public class Impl<B extends Inter, T extends Abs1<B>> extends Abs2<T> {...}
```

I have a hunch that in Scala with the traits there exists a more elegant solution, but are there any tips for Java?

Comment: `public class Impl<B extends Inter, T Abs1<B>> extends Abs2<T> {...}`.. did you miss something here?

Comment: @CKing Indeed, an `extends` was missing, post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... well, this is embarrassing. I was so focused on the F-Bound, that I forgot that this comes directly from the [JLS, section 4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed. If a bound is declared, it consists of either:
>
> - a single type variable `T`, or
> - a class or interface type `T` possibly followed by interface types `I1 & ... & In`.

In other words the (abstract) class declaration **must** come first in an intersection type. The described behaviour has nothing to do with F-Boundedness. I.e., the following works:

```
public class Impl<T extends Abs1<T> & Inter> extends Abs2<T> {...}
```

This is also described in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). If one thinks about it, it is self-explanatory, hence this way the parser has an easy way to check for double-inheritance (which is prohibited).

Comment: Just saw your answer. I was surprised that we couldn't write something like that but didn't pay much attention on the order. I've never used type parameters that complicated...